# Show that the trace of T*T is the sum of squares

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $a_{jk} \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$\sum_{(j, k) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}}^{\infty}\left|a_{j k}\right|^{2}<\infty.$$
For $f\in l^2(\mathbb N)$ define $Tf$ by
$$Tf(j)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{j k} f(k), \quad j \in \mathbb{N}.$$
By spectral theorem, we know that there is an orthonormal basis $\{v_n\}$ which consists of eigenvectors of $T^*T$. Let $\{\mu_n\}$ be the corresponding eigenvalues. We want to show that

$$\sum_{(j, k) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}}\left|a_{j k}\right|^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\|T v_{n}\right\|^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_{n}.$$

The right part is trivial from the definition of eigenvalues. However, I don't know how to do the left part. It looks like the trace of $T^*T$. In the finite dimensional case, we can use the fact that the trace is invariant under orthogonal transformation. Any hints?

Comment: The trace is invariant under unitary changes of basis in infinitely many dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{v_n\}$ and $\{w_n\}$ are two orthonormal bases then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Tv_n\|^2 =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty |\langle Tv_n, w_m\rangle|^2 = $$$$ =
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle v_n, T^*w_m\rangle|^2 =
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \|T^*w_m\|^2.
$$

This shows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Tv_n\|^2$ does not depend on the choice of basis.

On the other hand, if we take the canonical basis $\{e_n\}$, then we have
$$
  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \|Te_n\|^2 = 
  \sum_{(j,k)\in\mathbb N^2}|a_{jk}|^2,
  $$
thus proving the "left part", as required by the OP.

Comment: Why can we replace $T^*$ by $T$?

Comment: If you take a third basis $\{u_n\}$ then
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Tv_n\|^2 =
  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \|T^*w_m\|^2,
  $$
  and
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Tu_n\|^2 =
  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \|T^*w_m\|^2.
  $$
  Therefore
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Tv_n\|^2 =
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Tu_n\|^2.
  $$

Comment: Wow, that's really clever. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that simply taking $\{v_n\} = \{w_n\}$ is enough to show the above.